# Steps to solve this system of equations: $\sqrt{x}+y=7$, $\sqrt{y}+x=11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

I want to solve this system of equations, I have been out of Maths for a long!!

$$\sqrt{x}+y=7$$

$$\sqrt{y}+x=11$$

Just wondering easiest step to find values for $x$ and $y$ from the above equations?

Comment: When you say you 'want to solve this equation', do you mean solve for $y$? or $x$?

Comment: John, it seems to mean "solve this [system of] equation[s]"

Comment: Since the OP has presented us with two equations in two unknowns, I imagine that he wants us to solve for both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This is one of those `awkward' questions. Equations of this form (with $a$ and $b$ replacing 7 and 11) reduce to quartics, which do have analytic solutions, but they're pretty horrible. On the other hand, these *particular* equations have an integral solution.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor (9,4) is the only one.

Comment: @john w, solve is to get values for x and y

Comment: Why is "slope of a line" in the title?

Comment: @AméricoTavares , I should have explained Derivation for x and y !!  My initial hunch on deriving the above equation was based on y = mx + b !! Its my fault,

Comment: @Medex: I changed the title and retagged your question.

Comment: @Medex: I corrected the English in the title. It was my fault. And changed slightly the last sentence too.

Comment: Another question about the same system: [(Dis)prove that this system has only integral solutions: $\sqrt x+y=7$and $\sqrt y+x=11$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/602248)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that : $x,y \geq 0$

$(7-y)^2=11-\sqrt y$

substitute  $~\sqrt y = t~$ , so :

$(7-t^2)^2=11-t \Rightarrow t^4-14 \cdot t^2+49=11-t \Rightarrow t^4-14 \cdot t^2+t+38=0$

Note that  possible nonnegative integer solutions of equation  $~\sqrt x+y=7~$ are :

$(x,y) \in \{(1,6),(4,5),(9,4),(16,3),(25,2),(36,1),(49,0) \}$

Since pair $(x,y)$ has to be solution of equation $\sqrt y +x =11$ also we have that :

$(x,y)=(9,4) \Rightarrow \sqrt y=2 \Rightarrow t=2 ~$

Therefore polynomial $~t^4-14 \cdot t^2+t+38~$ has to be divisible by $(t-2)$

If you divide this polynomial by $(~t-2)~$ using [Polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Example) method you will get polynomial :

$t^3+2t^2-10t-19$

So you should solve equation $~t^3+2t^2-10t-19=0~$ to obtain other solutions .

This can be done using [general formula of roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots) .

Comment: I am able to derive upto this equation t ^ 4 −14 ^ t ^ 2 +t+38=0 , from then i am lost !! Can you please explain the rest

Comment: I said upto this step : t 4 −14⋅t 2 +t+38=0

Comment: @Medex,see edit...

Comment: @TPedja Great Thank you !! Your Derivation helped me a lot !!

Answer (score 7):

First rearrange the equations like this:
$$y-4=3-\sqrt{x} \\x-9=2-\sqrt{y}$$ 
then multiply two sides of these equations to each other;
$$(y-4)(x-9)=(3-\sqrt{x})(2-\sqrt{y})$$
Since $x,y\ge 0$ we can factor LHS :
$$(\sqrt{y}-2)(\sqrt{y}+2)(\sqrt{x}-3)(\sqrt{x}+3)=(3-\sqrt{x})(2-\sqrt{y})$$
Implies that$$ (\sqrt{y}-2)(\sqrt{x}-3)((\sqrt{y}+2)(\sqrt{x}+3)-1)=0 $$
at least one of the factors must be zero.

**1.** $$(\sqrt{y}-2)=0 \Rightarrow y=4$$

by substitution $y=4$ in the first eq. we have $x=9$.

and by checking in the second eq. implies that  $$x=9\qquad and \qquad y=4$$ is a solution.

or

**2.** $$(\sqrt{x}-3)=0 \Rightarrow x=9$$

by substitution in the first eq. we have $y=4$  and by checking in the second eq. implies that this is not a new solution.

or

**3.** $$(\sqrt{y}+2)(\sqrt{x}+3)-1=0 \Rightarrow (\sqrt{y}+2)(\sqrt{x}+3)=1$$
but it has no solution for $x$ and $y$ because 
 $$ (\sqrt{y}+2)\ge 2 ; \quad (\sqrt{x}+3) \ge 3 \Rightarrow (\sqrt{y}+2)(\sqrt{x}+3)\ge 6 $$
as a result $(\sqrt{y}+2)(\sqrt{x}+3)=1$ has no solution for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 5):

There are no easy steps to solve the given system of two equations
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{x}+y &=&7  \tag{1} \\
\sqrt{y}+x &=&11,  
\end{eqnarray}$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{x} &=&7-y \\
\sqrt{y} &=&11-x.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
If you square both equations you get
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=&\left( 7-y\right) ^{2} \\
y &=&\left( 11-x\right) ^{2},
\end{eqnarray*}$$
whose solutions include the solutions of the given system. Now substitute
the second in the first and vice-versa
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=&\left( 7-\left( 11-x\right) ^{2}\right) ^{2}\Leftrightarrow \left(
7-\left( 11-x\right) ^{2}\right) ^{2}-x=0 \\
y &=&\left( 11-\left( 7-y\right) ^{2}\right) ^{2}\Leftrightarrow \left(
11-\left( 7-y\right) ^{2}\right) ^{2}-y=0
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and expand the left hand sides to get two quartics
$$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
x^{4}-44x^{3}+712x^{2}-5017x+12\,996 &=&0  \tag{2} \\
y^{4}-28y^{3}+272y^{2}-1065y+1444 &=&0.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Instead of solving these two equations by the standard method, we can first
apply the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), from which we know
that the possible integer roots are of the form $x=\pm p,y=\pm q$, where $p$
and $q$ are integer factors of the constant terms, respectively, $
12996=2^{2}3^{2}19^{2}$ and $1444=2^{2}19^{2}$. By direct computation we
conclude that only $x=9$ and $y=4$ are integer solutions
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{9} &=&7-4 \\
\sqrt{4}+9 &=&11.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Since
$$\begin{eqnarray*}x^{4}-44x^{3}+712x^{2}-5017x+12996=\left( x-9\right) \left( x^{3}-35x^{2}+397x-1444\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}y^{4}-28y^{3}+272y^{2}-1065y+1444 =\left( y-4\right) \left( y^{3}-24y^{2}+176y-361\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
we still need to find the roots of two cubic equations, one in $x$ and the
other in $y$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x^{3}-35x^{2}+397x-1444 &=&0  \tag{3} \\
y^{3}-24y^{2}+176y-361 &=&0.  
\end{eqnarray}$$

It would be possible to find the roots algebraically, but the computation is
so long that I computed the roots numerically in SWP
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x &\approx &7.8687,\quad x \approx 12.848,\quad x \approx 14.283 \\
y &\approx &3.4156,\quad y \approx 9.8051,\quad y \approx 10.779.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

*Edited*. However these solutions are not solutions of the original system. For
instance, for $x\approx 7.8687$, from $\sqrt{7.868\,7}+y=7$, we find $
y\approx 4.1949$, which is not a solution of $\sqrt{y}+x=11$
$$
\sqrt{4.1949}+7.8687\approx 9.9168\neq 11,
$$
and similarly for the other solutions. So the only solution is $\left(
x,y\right) =\left( 9,4\right) $.

*Added*. Here is a plot of the two curves, $\sqrt{x}+y=7$ (blue) and $\sqrt{y}+x=11$  (black), which cross each other at $(x,y)=(9,4)$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have noticed that you have included a more detailed answer with a graph, so I will remove my previous answer.

Comment: @EmmadKareem You are welcome.

Comment: @AméricoTavares, Great help ! You also have changed the title and made it easier !! Thank you so much !!

Comment: @Medex You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I'll solve a related system of equations: $$A + B^2 = 7$$ and $$B +A^2=11$$

Solving for $A$ in the first gives $$A=7-B^2$$
Substituting this into the second equation gives $$B+(7-B^2)^2 = 11$$ from which we arrive at $$B^4 -14B^2+B+38=0$$

---

*Added*
Here, my goal is to find *some solution(s)* to this quartic (i.e. fourth degree) equation. There is a theoretical result that tells us what the **rational** (this includes integers) solutions will be, if there are any.

Basically, the rational root theorem says that in this case, any rational root will divide $38$.

We (the royal we ... I) then employ a technique known as *synthetic (polynomial) division*. I will not go into much detail, except to mention that I usually test smaller potential roots first... so testing $\pm 1, \pm 2 $ gives us that $B = 2$ is a solution. When we have exhausted our potential rational roots, we see that this is the only rational solution.

It then follows that $A=3$, since if $B = 2$, the first equation can be rewritten as $$A + 2^2 = 7$$

Comment: Rationality of solutions is not an issue here. The solution $(9,4)$ has already been identified. It remains to prove that there are no other solutions.

Comment: @Christian: the OP asked for *steps* in determining solutions. While you might not accept my solution of a related problem, neither do I accept an identification of a solution when a student has asked for a method.

Comment: @TheChaz , I am able to understand your last part of the derivation .. B4−14B2+B+38=0 , From then can you please explain me how you are able to generate B=2 and A=3

Comment: @TheChaz Great Thank you !! Your Derivation was simple and easy to follow !! Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked for the "easiest steps" to solve this system of equations. Here is what I would do:

Given that the occurring expressions are so simple I would try to get a global overview by drawing a figure. This means that we have to intersect the two graphs
$$y=7-\sqrt{x}\quad(x\geq0)\ ,\qquad y=(11-x)^2\quad(x\leq11)$$
(note restriction of $x$ for the second graph!). Looking at the figure one immediately sees that there is exactly one intersection point; one guesses that this is the point $(9,4)$. Plugging this point into the original system of equations one verifies that it is indeed a solution.

In order to prove that we were not cheated by our eyes we have to prove that the auxiliary function
$$f(x)\ :=\ (11-x)^2-(7-\sqrt{x})=114-22x+x^2+\sqrt{x}$$
has exactly one zero in the interval $[0,11]$. Unfortunately the derivative
$$f'(x)=-22+2x+{1\over 2\sqrt{x}}$$
is not strictly negative in this interval; so we have to take some extra measures:
When $0\leq x\leq5$ then $f(x)\geq 114-22x\geq4$, and when $10\leq x\leq11$ then $f(x)\leq 1-7+\sqrt{x} < -2$. For the intermediate interval $[5,10]$ we now can show that $f$ is strictly decreasing:
$$f'(x)\leq -22+20+{1\over 2\sqrt{5}} < -1\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

we can rewrite equations as $(x-4)+\sqrt{y}-3=0$,$(y-9)+\sqrt{x}-2=0$ so we have 
$(\sqrt{x}-2)(\sqrt{x}+2)+\sqrt{y}-3=0$ ,$(\sqrt{y}-3)(\sqrt{y}+3)+\sqrt{x}-2=0$ substitute $\sqrt y$ from first equation and factor we have $(\sqrt{x}-2)((\sqrt{x}+2)(\sqrt{y}+3)-1)=0$ so we have $x=4,y=9$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$x=\tan^2\theta$
and $y=\sec^2\theta$

1. $\tan\theta+\sec^2\theta=7$
2. $\tan^2\theta+\sec\theta=11$

Take 1) $\tan\theta+1/\cos^2\theta=7$
Solve it and you will get

$$7\sin^2\theta+\sin\theta-6=0$\tag{A}$$

Now similarly take equation (2) solve it 
you will get

$$12\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta-1=0\tag{B}$$

Take (A). 
Let 
$\sin\theta=t$,  $7t^2+t-6=0$.

Solve it you will get 
$t=-1$  or   $t=6/7$

$\sin\theta=-1$  or $\sin\theta=6/7$.

Now

Take eq. (B)

Do similarly
As equation (A)

$12\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta-1=0$

Solve it as above 
$\cos\theta=1/3$ or  $\cos\theta=-1/4$

$\cos\theta$ value exists in 3 quadrant not -ve

So $-1/4$ not possible.

$\cos\theta=1/3$

$\sin\theta$ value exist in 3 quadrant not +ve  so 
$\sin\theta=-1$.

Now $\tan\theta=\sin\theta/\cos\theta=-1/(1/3)=-3$.

$x=\tan^2\theta=(-3)^2=9$

Put in equation 1 $y=4$

Therefore 
$x=9$    and $y=4$ is answer.