# How to solve this problem? You got to find $x$ and $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

The problem is to find $x$ and $y$.
$$\sqrt x + y = 7$$
$$\sqrt y +x = 11$$
I know what the answer is, but I am confused about how to get the answer.
Here’s the picture of the problem: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/7Q8asNU

Comment: Graphing the two equations and finding their point of intersection is one of the ways to go; it seems much more troublesome analytically.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144910/system-of-equations-x2y-7-y2x-11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System of equations: $x^2+y=7, y^2+x=11$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144910/system-of-equations-x2y-7-y2x-11)

Comment: That is not a solution. @Manan

Comment: @WilliamElliot It does reveal one of the solutions, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x}=7-y$$

$$\sqrt{y}=11-x$$

Square both sides of each:

$$x=49-14y+y^2$$

$$y=121-22x+x^2$$

Substitute the first equation into the second:

$$y=121 -22(49-14y+y^2) + (49-14y+y^2)^2$$

And you have a quartic in $y$. Be careful with the solutions that you get, though. Squaring both sides can create extra solutions to the equation so you'll need to substitute them back into the your original system to check which ones are valid.

Comment: You can factor the last equation and be left with a cubic.