# Solve the system of equation

Tags: systems-of-equations

Solve the system of equations :\

$x+y^2=7$
$x^2+y=11$ 
my attempt :
$$x=7-y^2 \implies (7-y^2)^2 +y = 11 \text{ Hence }  y^4-14y^2+y+38=0 $$  
i'm stuck here any help

Comment: The formula for biquadratic equations give only complicated complex solutions, sorry.

Comment: @vonbrand It's not biquadratic as there is a $y$ term.

Comment: @vonbrand but for example $(3,2)$ is a solution of the system

Comment: Unfortunately, $ \ (3 \ , \ 2) \ $ is the only "nice" solution.  The "horizontal" and "vertical" parabolas so described do have four intersections, but three of them have irrational coordinates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System of equations: $x^2+y=7, y^2+x=11$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144910/system-of-equations-x2y-7-y2x-11). If you search your question on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz), you will find this one.

Comment: There's a slightly earlier version of the problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108962/steps-to-solve-this-system-of-equations-sqrtxy-7-sqrtyx-11  .  After about ten years, it looks like the "beautiful" way to solve this system has yet to be posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=7-y^2 \implies (7-y^2)^2 +y = 11 \text{ Hence }  y^4-14y^2+y+38=0$$

With $y=2$ we get $$16-56+2+38=0$$

Thus we have one solution, $ x=3, y=2 $
finding other solutions involves solving a cubic polynomial.$$y^3+2y^2-10y-19=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x+y^2=7\Rightarrow x=7-y^2$$
sub in:
$$(7-y^2)^2+y=11$$
solve this for values of $y$ (pretty hard to do by hand) then sub back in to find values of $x$. As you may be able to tell, there should be $4$ solutions, only one of which has integer values.

This is just an extension of what you said really, I'm not sure of a method that doesn't yield a quartic